# show bigger img on hover using img from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, css, image

I have a login system so I can't use specific images in my php files.
For example I use the following code: `<img src="<?= $gebruiker->getImg(); ?>" />` to get the right profile picture from the person who is logged in.

Now my problem, Since I use this, I can't use specific images on hover.
So how can I use the image which I get from `getImg();` and make a bigger thumbnail on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your images such as "profile-pic":

```
<img src="<?= $gebruiker->getImg(); ?>" class="profile-pic" />
```

In your CSS, you can then do something like this:

```
.profile-pic:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); /* will scale the image by 1.1x */
}
```